# On animation end view coordinates are the same as on start

Tags: android, android-animation

I have the following layout which consists of two `EditText`s inside the same parent :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et_profession"
    android:hint="Profession"
    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
    android:layout_marginLeft="32dp" android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="48dp" android:inputType="text"
    tools:ignore="LabelFor" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et_company"
    android:hint="Company"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:layout_marginLeft="32dp" android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="48dp" android:inputType="text"
    tools:ignore="LabelFor" />

</LinearLayout>
```

What I want is when user presses the next action button on his keyboard for the first editText to animate the second editText to the position of the first.

And this is the code how I' ve done it :

```
private void startCompanyAnim() {
    etCompany.animate()
            .setDuration(2000L)
            .setListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
                    etCompany.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                    Log.i("ANIM", "START : prof.TOP == " + etProfession.getTop() + " and comp.TOP == " + etCompany.getTop());
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    Log.i("ANIM", "END : prof.TOP == " + etProfession.getTop() + " and comp.TOP == " + etCompany.getTop());
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

                }
            })
            .translationY(etProfession.getTop() - etCompany.getTop())
            .start();
}
```

While this seems to work and the second view is on top of the first, the problem is that when I'm logging the `getTop()` value for the second editText is the same as it was before the animation.

For example here's what I got on logcat :

```
01-20 09:08:25.646 2014-2014/com.anim.androidanimations I/ANIM: START : prof.TOP == 0 and comp.TOP == 72
 01-20 09:08:27.655 2014-2014/com.anim.androidanimations I/ANIM: END : prof.TOP == 0 and comp.TOP == 72
```

Shouldn't the logged `getTop()` for the second view `onAnimationEnd()` have the same value as the first one? Also since I can see it on my device's screen that is indeed on top of the first why it gives me the same value as before the animation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case this is the simple way to this.

```
 @Override
 public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
    etCompany.layout(etProfession.getLeft(),etProfession.getTop(),etProfession.getRight(),etProfession.getBottom());
    Log.i("ANIM", "END : prof.TOP == " + etProfession.getTop() + " and comp.TOP == " + etCompany.getTop());
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to change as follows:

```
private void startCompanyAnim() {
    etCompany.animate()
            // ...
            .yBy(etProfession.getTop() - etCompany.getTop())
            .start();
}
```

This will affect the Y property directly.

Comment: Nope, still the same. Animation works but the logged `getTop()` value is the same as before the anim.

Comment: Hm.. the following should work:
`int dy = etProfession.getTop() - etCompany.getTop();
    etCompany.animate()
            .translationY(dy)
            .withEndAction(() -> etCompany.setTranslationY(etCompany.getTranslationY() - dy))
           .start();`